# Raw socket: unexpected IP header added when sending self-made IP/TCP packets

Tags: sockets, network-programming, raw-sockets

I want to use raw socket to send TCP packets which is a full IP packet(so the packet has IP header, TCP header and TCP payload, but has no ethernet header. The IP source and destination addresses are in a WLAN, 192.168.0.105 and 192.168.0.103), with the following codes

```
    int on;
    on = 0;
    if ((sendfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
            perror("raw socket");
            exit(1);
    }
    if (setsockopt(sendfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
    }

    nr_bytes = sendto(sendfd, packet, ip_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, addr_len);
```

I use TCPdump to capture the sent-out packet and notice it has added an additional IP header to the IP packet, and the IP protocol number is 255（ip->ip_p is 255）. So it has two IP headers(with same pair of src and dst IP), which is unexpected.

what are the problems? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IPPROTO_RAW` implicitly enables the option `IP_HDRINCL`.
In your call to `setsockopt()` you disable `IP_HDRINCL` again because you set `on = 0`.
Try removing the `setsockopt()` or setting `on = 1`.